# Create GroupBox and labels inside it programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a groupbox programmatically and inside it put labels. Now I created this but with design and I have like this:

[image]

I'm trying but I don't know how can I assign labels in correct position and how can I assign it to a specific group box

```
GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
Panel grid1 = new Panel();
Label lbl1 = new Label { Text = "Completed" };
Label lbl2 = new Label { Text = "label" };
Label lbl3 = new Label { Text = "In progress" };
Label lbl4 = new Label { Text = "label" };
//etcetera
groupBox1.Width = 185;
groupBox1.Height = 160;
grid1.Height = 185;
grid1.Width = 160;
```

How can I achieve that? Regards
 **Update**

As the comments below I try

```
GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
                    this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);
                    Panel grid1 = new Panel();
                    groupBox1.Controls.Add(grid1);
                    groupBox1.Location = new Point(20, 250);
                    grid1.Location = new Point(20, 250);
                    Label lbl1 = new Label { Text = "test" };
                    Label lbl2 = new Label { Text = "Test2" };
                    groupBox1.Name = "TESTTT";
                    groupBox1.Width = 222;
                    groupBox1.Height = 149;

                    grid1.Height = 218;
                    grid1.Width = 145;
                    grid1.Controls.Add(lbl1);
                    grid1.Controls.Add(lbl2);
```

Result:
[image]

But my group box it just clear without name and without labels, why it happen?

Comment: Use `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Every container control has a Controls collection.  You "Add" your controls to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls in `WinForms` are arranged so that they reside inside one another. So your `Form` has a `Controls` collection which is essentially a `Collection` of type `Control`. So if you add a `GroupBox` to the form, then you must add it to the `Controls` collection of the form. Then if you add a control to your `GroupBox` then you need to add it to the `GroupBox` collection of controls.

With that in mind, you can do something like this:

```
private void AddGroupBoxAndLables()
{
    GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
    groupBox1.SetBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
    this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);

    Label lblCompleted = new Label { Name = "lblCompleted", Text = "Completed" };
    lblCompleted.Location = new Point(20, 20);
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(lblCompleted);
    Label valCompleted = new Label { Name = "valCompleted" };
    valCompleted.Location = new Point(80, 20);
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(valCompleted);

    Label lblInProgress = new Label { Name = "lblInProgress", Text = "In Progress" };
    lblInProgress.Location = new Point(20, 60);
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(lblInProgress);
    Label valInProgress = new Label { Name = "valInProgress" };
    valInProgress.Location = new Point(80, 60);
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(valInProgress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way for solution is that your code is already created when you did design. Code is created automatically in respective form's designer.cs or designer.vb file. To see this file, in solution explorer click on button 'Show all files'. Still for your understanding let me explain code

You have created groupbox using 
    GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
To see this group box on form you need to add this groupbox to form
    this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);

Similar in case of panel. If you want to add panel inside of groupbox then
   groupbox1.Controls.Add(grid1);

Then add all labels inside of panel.

You will find similar kind of code in form's designer.cs.

Comment: And how do you set positions? as Example: lbl1 besides lbl2 , then do a breakline and set lbl3 besides lbl4?

Comment: These all things are done using respective control's location property. You need to increase y coordinate for breakline. Just check once designer.cs code, it will be good for your reference and understanding. Tablelayout is also good option but then you need add tablelayout inside group box and in each table cell you need to put respective labels.

Comment: I try as you say but I just get empty groupbox? any idea why? I update my question with my try

Comment: @Rene Your labels have no size.

Comment: As @larstech said please add sizes of labels. Also set location (x,y) properly.